# Is it OK to ask a quesiton where to find a CI/DC DevOps process for Salesforce only utilizing Salesforce, GitHub, and a free automation tool?

Tags: discussion

I'm putting together some DevOps process options that include version control and CI/CD. They want to see options that include 3rd party tools that charge fees (such as Gearset), and "free" options.

Before posting this question, is it too subjective or out of scope for the main site?

Answer (score 1):

If your question boils down to "which of these tools is best" then yes, it is likely too opinion based to be on topic. If you have a question which seeks objective information about specific tools, then it may be on topic, as long as it doesn't combine too many different questions into one post.

Comment: What if the question was setup like "Is there a Salesforce recommended best practice for DevOps and CI/CD using non 3rd party products?" or something similar?

Comment: Yeah that sounds super opinion based to me.

Comment: I assume this style of question is still appropriate for the chat channel?

Comment: Yes, spinning up a chat would be a perfectly appropriate discussion venue, if you can drum up participants.